# How to make function "make_archive" to include the parent directory in python

Tags: python, linux, archive

I am using [shutil.make_archive](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html) function to make archive

But it only archive the contents of directory.
i have the folder to backup like  `root_dir = /home/john/public_html`

I use that then my archive contains the contents of public_html but i want to include public_html itself in archive.

Now in my `john` folder i have many other folders as well that i don't want to backup so i can't use /home/john

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass the `base_dir` argument, as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#archiving-operations):

```
shutil.make_archive('public_html_backup', 'zip', '/home/john', '/home/john/public_html')
```

Comment: do base_dir has to be the full path or it is realtive to the root path. i mean public_html or /home/john/public_html